# SQL Execute won't execute UCP with string format

Tags: python, sql, database, execute

I am trying to call this UCP I have written and it takes in some variables as input. When I run the following code, it works.

```
try:

    cursor.execute("PYH_uspUpdateConversation @lngConversationID=1020910, @lngNodeID=2, @strText='WAZZAA', @strResponse='sup', @strSentiment=0.98")
except pyodbc.Error:
    print('Error !!!!! %s' % pyodbc.Error)
print ("\nResults :")
recs = cursor.fetchall()
print(recs[0][0])
```

However, when I execute the same code like this:

```
try:
    cursor.execute(f"PYH_uspUpdateConversation @lngConversationID={id}, @lngNodeID={nodeID}, @strText={text}, @strResponse={resp}, @strSentiment={sentiment}")
except pyodbc.Error:
    print('Error !!!!! %s' % pyodbc.Error)
print ("\nResults :")
recs = cursor.fetchall()
print(recs[0][0])
```

I get an error saying that it is not a valid SQL statement: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

Comment: Appears that the variables are not being passed successfully.  Can you print the variable values before calling the cursor?

Comment: @alexherm Here is what happened when I printed out the execution string: {PYH_uspUpdateConversation @lngConversationID= 'ac7229d3-6a21-4694-92fb-f37273967924', @lngNodeID= 1, @strText= 'Wazz', @strResponse= 'Glad to hear that. I just have a few questions to go through if you don't mind?', @strSentiment= 0.7532452}

Comment: UPDATE: I altered some of the values and the new output is this: {PYH_uspUpdateConversation @lngConversationID= 3, @lngNodeID= 1, @strText= 'Wazz', @strResponse= 'Glad to hear that. I just have a few questions to go through if you don't mind?', @strSentiment= '0.7532452'}

Comment: Still the same error though